# Firefox strokeText jagged artifacts

Tags: javascript, firefox, text, canvas, rendering

having some issues with canvas rendering of strokeText() in FF. Whenever drawing outline text with the code:

```
canvasCtx.font          = '36px impact';
canvasCtx.strokeStyle   = '#000';
canvasCtx.fillStyle     = '#fff';
canvasCtx.lineWidth     = 4;

canvasCtx.strokeText('DIG IN CEREAL', 20, 20);
```

Chrome gives me [no artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MViu.png).
FF gives me jagged [artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrIMu.png).

Basically this is being rendered on the canvas and then exported with toDataUrl(). 
Anyone know a workaround / why the jagged artifacts would happen only in FF? Thanks.

Comment: Artifacts also present in Opera, so I'm hesitant to simply report this as a bug on any specific rendering engine

Comment: Someone just recently posted this in Opera forums (http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1515822&t=1345656952&page=1) so hopefully this gets some attention. Have you reported a bug with Mozilla?

Comment: I am seeing this in Chrome (using KineticJS, but I think the problem is with the underlying canvas) especially with the letter 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into this through node-canvas serverside.  Since I'm only using text in isolated incidences, I'm able to clip a rectangle around my text, but it's likely to be specific to my font.

```
  x = 10
  y = 10
  @fontSize = 104
  @context.font = 'bold ' + @fontSize + ' Arial'

  @context.save()
  @context.beginPath()
  @context.rect x - @fontSize*.1, y - @fontSize*.68 - @context.lineWidth, @context.measureText(text).width + @fontSize * .2, @fontSize + @context.lineWidth
  @context.clip()
  @context.strokeText text, x, y
  @context.fillText text, x, y
  @context.restore()
```

So, this is a snippet taken from coffeescript, but you should get the idea... `save, clip, stroke/draw, restore`.

You will have to play with the `*.1`, `*.775`, etc

You actually could make the horizontal part of the rect much bigger ( instead of `.1`, you could use `10` and instead of `.2`, use `20` ), since you're not worried about artifacts to the and to the right.
The `.775` was the exact number for me to clip off exactly the top of

So yea, kind of a hack, but it worked around the problem for me.